# Why is my connection string not found, when I am referencing the project where it exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have built a separate data layer which contains my Entity Framework. I made a reference to this separate project in my current project ... I added the following to my current MVC controller:

```
using SMCD_DataLayer;

  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel lv)
        {
            var db = new SMCD_DataStoreEntities();
            var found = db.Users.Select(x => x.Username == lv.userId && x.Password == lv.passWord).Any();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!found)
                {
                    lv.errorMsg = "User ID is invalid!";
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("IntroPage", "Devices");
                }
            }

            return View(lv);
        }
```

my SMCD_DataStoreEntities lives in SMCD_DataLayer, but this controller lives in SMCD_Portal Project.

on the line var found ... I am getting the following error message:

System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=No connection string named 'SMCD_DataStoreEntities' could be found in the application config file.

The connection string lives in the SMCD_Datalayer, even though I am referencing it in my current project, does it need to live in the SMCD_Portal Project?

This is the connection string which lives in the App.config in the SMCD_DataLayer, remember my controller lives in SMCD_Portal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SMCD_DataStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=&quot;res://*/SMCD DataStore.csdl|res://*/SMCD DataStore.ssdl|res://*/SMCD DataStore.msl&quot;;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=KARL-LT\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SMCD_DataStore;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code.  None of the code you have current provided shows a connection string.  Nor have you provided your connection string from your web.config (or related resource).  **remove the actual connection string information, we do not need to know the host, db name, username or password**.

Comment: sure I can show that to you

Comment: my main question is ... can the Entity Framework live in another project or does it have to live in my current project where my controller is using it?

Comment: Your question doesn't sound anywhere remotely like that.  But the direct answer is no, your MVC application does not have to have any references to EF if the solution and projects are laid out correctly.  (other than the web.config)

Comment: However, your connection string needs to be in the .config file for your MVC app. Including it in the config file of a class library won't work.

Comment: so if I include it in my MVC app ... this would work

Comment: I got this to work by adding the connection string to my web.config file in my SMCD_Portal, but the Entity Framework lives in SMCD_DataLayer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any .config settings that are used by your application, or used by any referenced assemblies, will generally need to be in the main application's .config file.

The same applies for connection strings.

So put those connection strings in your main application's .config file and you should be alright.